# SwiftUI appears different in simulator than on device for watchOS

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchos

I've been designing my SwiftUI watchOS app using Xcode Preview and the Simulator. Everything looks great, but then when I ran it on a real device everything looks different. Some padding disappears, frame width/height is ignored in some place, text autoresizing becomes tiny.

What happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: Post your code & screenshots of Preview & Simulator or rel Device. Sounds like a problem with the sequence that you are placing certain attributes/modifiers (like padding, etc)./ If you post more details we can help you.